# Как правильно развернуть интернет - магазин на Heroku?

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, развертывание, redis

Создал интернет-магазин на Django. На борту установлены Celery, Redis.
На локальном сервере все работает замечательно
Как разворачивать сайт на Heroku я знаю, но как правильно развернуть интернет-магазин ?
Я понимаю, что принципы те же, но как, например, будет работать сервер Redis в интернете, если он работает сейчас у меня локально ('redis://127.0.0.1:6379/'), какие изменения мне стоить внести, чтобы Redis так же работал и вне моей машины ?
Следует сказать, что у меня Windows.

Comment: [Раз](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis) и [два](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku).

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать Docker для удобства развёртывания и настройки сопрограмм, вот хороший гайд:

https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-heroku-with-docker/

А здесь используют Redis

https://www.capside.com/labs/deploying-full-django-stack-with-docker-compose/

Comment: Почитал, было полезно, спасибо)